# Insert CSV into one column of table as every value a new row

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a stored procedure in which i am receiving a CSV string parameter. I want to read each value from CSV and insert into table column one by one as each value into new row.

Please help

Comment: Are you trying to insert all of these values into a single column?  If so, just wrap the entire string in single quotes.

Comment: i want 1 in row1, 2 in row2, 3 in row3. Not all in one column

Comment: OK - you need to update the original post to make that a lot more clear.  I'm not the one who downvoted you, but you do definitely need more detail. I'll post an answer in a minute with some code that might help you - in the meantime, please update your post.

Comment: @user3506132 - is this for sql server or mysql ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty simple example - unlike your original posting, the values aren't comma-separated.  Your post isn't clear enough for me to know if this will satisfy your question or not.

```
INSERT INTO Table (Column)

SELECT 1 UNION 
SELECT 2 UNION 
SELECT 3

SELECT * FROM Table
```

Comment: You're welcome.  Once again, I'm not sure what you are hoping to accomplish by "separate csv into string" - please update your original question with full details and we'll do our best to help you out.